# Entity Framework 5 WARNING when working with a non-local workspace

Tags: entity-framework-5

I am getting the following WARNING from the emdx designer when working with my code from a shared workspace instead of the workspace being local on my own box. We need to work from a workspace off of our box.

How can I resolve the issue where it won't give me that warning?

Warning 1   The path '\bhg-colo-sq04\User Workspaces\wyeager\Development\WebProject\PDFConverter\PDFConverterModel\PDFConverterModel\EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude' must be either local to this computer or part of your trusted zone. If you have downloaded this template, you may need to 'Unblock' it using the properties page for the template file in File Explorer. \bhg-colo-sq04\User Workspaces\wyeager\Development\WebProject\PDFConverter\PDFConverterModel\PDFConverterModel\Vision.tt   0   0   PDFConverterModel

Comment: Rightclick on the file and there should be "Unblock" button that you need to click.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the host where the C# project is located to trusted hosts. Open your Internet Explorer settings, choose the tab Security and choose the icon Trusted Hosts. You'll see the button Hosts. Click on it and add the host to the list. I hope it helps.